# Matching regex in step definition

Tags: regex, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I have a Given statement in my feature file

```
Given I have $100.25 in my bank account
```

The following step definition is not picking up the decimal fraction

```
 @Given("I have \\$\\d+(\\.\\d+) in my bank account")
    public void given_money_in_bank_Account(double money){
      //This returns money as .25
    }
```

I am sure my regex is correct here. How can I get 100.25 passed as argument?

Comment: Try `\\$([0-9\\.]+)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misplaced group. It should be `I have \\$(\\d+\\.\\d+) in my bank account`.

But parsing floating point numbers with regex is not recommended. You have dozens of representation to represent a floating point number and the above regex only caters to a few.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo :-P